# taps migration failing from sqlite to postgres rails4, ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, sqlite, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, taps

I am trying to migrate my Rails app to Postgresql for heroku however i can't get taps to get the data from my SQLite3 database, here is what i have tried:

**Create the Postgres database user for the new databases**

```
$ createuser f3
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) n
Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) y
Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) y
```

**EDIT - Updated command below - use this instead**

```
$ createuser f3 -d -s
```

**Create the required databases**

```
$ createdb -Of3 -Eutf8 f3_development
$ createdb -Of3 -Eutf8 f3_test
```

**Update the Gemfile**

```
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'taps'
$ bundle
```

**Update database.yml**

```
#development:
#  adapter: sqlite3
#  database: db/development.sqlite3
#  pool: 5
#  timeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: f3_development
  pool: 5
  username: f3
  password:

#test:
#  adapter: sqlite3
#  database: db/test.sqlite3
#  pool: 5
#  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: f3_test
  pool: 5
  username: f3
  password:
```

**Start the taps server on the sqlite database**

```
$ taps server sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 user password
```

**Migrate the data**

```
$ taps pull postgres://f3@localhost/f3_development http://user:password@localhost:5000
```

This yields an error:

```
MacBook-Pro:devise_example-master david$ taps pull postgres://david:abc123@localhost/f3_development http://user:password@localhost:5000
Receiving schema
Unable to fetch tables information from http://user:password@localhost:5000. Please check the server log.
```

Anyone got a fix for this, (I cant just switch to Ruby 1.9.2 using rvm cause my app use a lot of gems that aren't working for the old ruby).

**And below is the Log from the taps sqlite server when pull is issued**

```
MacBook-Pro:devise_example-master david$ taps server sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 user password
== Sinatra/1.0 has taken the stage on 5000 for production with backup from WEBrick
[2013-08-13 21:38:23] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-08-13 21:38:23] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
[2013-08-13 21:38:23] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4357 port=5000
127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0011
localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31
- -> /
127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "POST /sessions HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0070
localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "POST /sessions HTTP/1.1" 200 46
- -> /sessions
Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error - cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations:
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:427:in `valenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `block in arrenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `map'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `arrenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:410:in `encode'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/server.rb:157:in `block in <class:Server>'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `instance_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `route_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `catch'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `block in route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `each'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `block in call!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `block in invoke'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `catch'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `invoke'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/auth/basic.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error: cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0112
localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 522
- -> /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names
Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error - cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations:
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:427:in `valenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `block in arrenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `map'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `arrenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:410:in `encode'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/server.rb:157:in `block in <class:Server>'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `instance_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `route_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `catch'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `block in route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `each'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `block in call!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `block in invoke'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `catch'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `invoke'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/auth/basic.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error: cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0048
localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 522
- -> /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names
Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error - cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations:
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:427:in `valenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `block in arrenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `map'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `arrenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:410:in `encode'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/server.rb:157:in `block in <class:Server>'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `instance_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `route_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `catch'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `block in route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `each'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `block in call!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `block in invoke'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `catch'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `invoke'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/auth/basic.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error: cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0043
localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 522
- -> /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names
Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error - cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations:
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:427:in `valenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `block in arrenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `map'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `arrenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:410:in `encode'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/server.rb:157:in `block in <class:Server>'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `instance_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `route_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `catch'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `block in route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `each'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `block in call!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `block in invoke'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `catch'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `invoke'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/auth/basic.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error: cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0046
localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 522
- -> /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names
Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error - cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations:
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:427:in
```

..................

lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
    ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error: cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations
    An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
    install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
    127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0045
    localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 522
    - -> /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names
    Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error - cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations:
     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:427:in`valenc'
     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `block in arrenc'
     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in`map'
     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `arrenc'
     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:410:in`encode'
     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/server.rb:157:in `block in <class:Server>'
     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in`call'
     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'
     /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in`instance_eval'

......

```
ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error: cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0050
localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 522
- -> /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names
Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error - cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations:
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:427:in `valenc'
```

......

```
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error: cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0045
localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 522
- -> /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names
Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error - cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations:
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:427:in `valenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `block in arrenc'
```

......

```
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error: cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0159
localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 522
- -> /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names
Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error - cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations:
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:427:in `valenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in
```

.......

```
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/auth/basic.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error: cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0048
localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 522
- -> /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names
Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error - cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations:
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:427:in `valenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `block in arrenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `map'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:438:in `arrenc'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/utils/okjson.rb:410:in `encode'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/server.rb:157:in `block in <class:Server>'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `instance_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `route_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `catch'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `block in route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `each'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `route!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `block in call!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `block in invoke'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `catch'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `invoke'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/auth/basic.rb:25:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
ERROR: Rack::Utils::OkJson::Error: cannot encode Symbol: :schema_migrations
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
127.0.0.1 - user [13/Aug/2013 21:38:32] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0045
localhost - - [13/Aug/2013:21:38:32 CEST] "GET /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names HTTP/1.1" 500 522
- -> /sessions/6475330165/pull/table_names
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. I went up one directory from my project directory then did the following
2. `gem install taps`
3. `gem uninstall rack`
4. `gem install rack --version 1.0.1`

Start the sqlite server from the project directory, in the 'one up directory' run:

```
taps pull postgres://f3@localhost/f3_development http://user:password@localhost:5000
```

Then did the migration as before and it worked. I had rack 1.5.2 installed so I had to remove that and replace it with rack 1.0.1. I'm using ruby 2.0.0-p0 and rails 4.0.0.beta1

It seems only the pull command needed the old version of rack so the server could run on the newer 1.5.2 version...

Comment: I had 2 different versions of rack installed besides 1.0.1. I had to remove them both.

Comment: I also had to uninstall my rack-1.6.4 version, then runs the taps pull command, then reinstall rack-1.6.4.

Answer (score 4):

@David Karlsson's answer worked for me too. Except I had to update back rack once taps has completed the pull

```
gem update rack
```

and run `bundle install` to get back all my gems working.

I'm on rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @DavidKarlsson, just adding to your answer, there is no need to uninstall the existing rack. Following the recommendation of @hak8or in https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/128 I used a Gemfile to ensure usage of rack version 1.0.1. But after I installed  I had various versions of rack

```
$ gem uninstall 'rack'

Select gem to uninstall:
1. rack-1.0.1
2. rack-1.4.4
3. rack-1.4.5
4. rack-1.5.2
5. All versions
```

and did not want to uninstall them, because that could affect other projects I have in the same machine. When I run taps it would use the latest, rack-1.5.2, so what I did was to run taps using bundle exec, in my case

```
bundle exec taps server sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 root root
```

Hope it helps!