# Moving from Sqlite3 to PostgreSQL Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I'm trying to move my database to a PostgreSQL because I'm putting it up on Heroku. 
Followed [Railscast #342](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql). Installed PostgreSLQ with its dependencies on my Ubuntu machine. When I installed it I think a user was created. I used this user in my database.yml. It looks like this:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dlrvbtApp1_production
  pool: 5
  username: jdartland
  password: 

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dlrvbtApp1_development
  pool: 5
  username: jdartland
  password: 

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dlrvbtApp1_test
  pool: 5
  username: jdartland
  password:
```

Installed [pg gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/pg) and the [taps gem](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps).
Ran a `Bundle install`, created the databases with `rake db:create:all`

Started the taps senatra server with `taps server sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 jdartland secure`

The server started. And tried to pull the SQL to my new development db through this command.

```
taps pull postgres://jdartland@localhost/dlrvbtApp1_development http://jdartland:secret@localhost:5000
```

**I then get this error:**

```
Failed to connect to database:
  Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I have tried and tried, created new databases, canhing the .yml, pg_config and so on but I can't get it to work. 
This is my first time working with PostgreSQL and Heroku, please give me a hand! :)

Comment: Ok dumb question....... but you say the error is that there is no password set. But you've got no password in your database.yml file?

Comment: Well tried with that aswell, get the same error. First time working with databases, dont know how to pass the authentication to my localhost sinatra database hosted with the taps gem on my local mashine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It working by following another post here on stack. Simply went up one directory, installed taps `Gem install Taps`. Uninstalled Rack gem `gem uninstall rack 4` then Reinstalled it `gem install rack --version 1.0.1`. Did not do this in my progect directory, just simply in RVM. Then Pulled the database from the same directory. (not from my project directory).

Here is the Whole tread: [taps migration failing from sqlite to postgres rails4, ruby 1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217886/taps-migration-failing-from-sqlite-to-postgres-rails4-ruby-1-9-3)

Hope it helps someone with the same problem.

**Now just one thing left, Push it to heroku..... We'll see how that goes...hehe**

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1):

Change the user on production to localhost and leave the password blank.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dlrvbtApp1_production
  pool: 5
  username: localhost
  password:
```

Comment: Should I do the same in development and test?

Comment: When I then do rake db:create:all I get FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "localhost"

Comment: Good deal. Check out this post to configure from here on out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres

Answer (score 1):

If you're moving your database to Heroku, the whole thing is just a case of connecting your DB to Heroku's PG one, and migrating the data.

**Did you receive database details from Heroku?**
They basically use Amazon to serve their DB's, and you'll get some credentials to put into your yml file for it. Here is an example of one of our live Heroku apps:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: ********
  pool: 5
  username: ****************
  password: ****************
  port: 5432
  host: ec2-54-228-234-250.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

**Ways To Migrate To PostgreSQL (Heroku)**

If you're looking to migrate your data from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL, I found a really good tutorial on how to do this [here](http://datachomp.com/archives/quickly-migrate-a-db-from-mysql-to-postgres/). Only problem is that it's not for SQLite lol

Comment: Haha thanks, yeah can be usefull in the future. Firstly I have to migrate from sqlite3 to postgresql. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to pull down your database from Heroku into a local postgres database, use `pg:pull` or pgbackups:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

You should also look into using foreman and a `.env` file to setup your DATABASE_URL similar to how it's ran on Heroku, for dev/prod parity:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#developing-locally-with-foreman

Comment: Im trying to pull it from My local sinatra Sqlite3 database to a PostgreSQL