# Taps Server Error: unitialized constant Config (migration from SQLite to Postgres)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I am trying to translate my rails SQLite database into Postgres database to ultimately deploy on Heroku. I have been troubleshooting taps following the guidances provided here [taps migration failing from sqlite to postgres rails4, ruby 1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217886/taps-migration-failing-from-sqlite-to-postgres-rails4-ruby-1-9-3).

I successfully started the taps server but I get the following error when I pull.

```
Receiving schema
Schema:          0%   | ETA:  --:--:--
Saving session to pull_201506052236.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: uninitialized constant Config
```

When I pull, the console where I entered the 'taps server' command line item shows an error as well:

```
ERROR: NameError: uninitialized constant Config
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
127.0.0.1 - bastien [05/Jun/2015 22:36:35] 
"POST /sessions/169975329    /pull/schema HTTP/1.1" 500 518 0.0039
localhost - - [05/Jun/2015:22:36:35 CEST] 
"POST /sessions/169975329 /pull/schema HTTP/1.1" 500 518
- -> /sessions/169975329/pull/schema
```

Can you please help me understand this issue and how it can be resolved?

Please see below the full log of both consoles

1) Console "pull"

```
Receiving schema
Schema:          0% |                                                                                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
Saving session to pull_201506052236.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: uninitialized constant Config
["/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/utils.rb:17:in `windows?'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/utils.rb:21:in `bin'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/utils.rb:132:in `schema_bin'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/server.rb:136:in `block in <class:Server>'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `call'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:865:in `block in route'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `instance_eval'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:521:in `route_eval'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:500:in `block (2 levels) in route!'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `catch'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:497:in `block in route!'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `each'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:476:in `route!'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:601:in `dispatch!'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `block in call!'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `instance_eval'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `block in invoke'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `catch'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:566:in `invoke'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:411:in `call!'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:399:in `call'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/deflater.rb:13:in `call'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/auth/basic.rb:25:in `call'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:20:in `_call'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:13:in `call'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `block in call'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1005:in `synchronize'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:979:in `call'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:50:in `service'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'", "/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'"]
```

2) Console 'taps server'

Initially after command 'taps server'

```
== Sinatra/1.0 has taken the stage on 5000 for production with backup from WEBrick
[2015-06-05 22:36:28] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-06-05 22:36:28] INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-06-05 22:36:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=9396 port=5000
```

Once I run 'pull' in the other console

```
127.0.0.1 - bastien [05/Jun/2015 22:36:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25 0.0008
localhost - - [05/Jun/2015:22:36:34 CEST] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 25
- -> /
127.0.0.1 - bastien [05/Jun/2015 22:36:35] "POST /sessions HTTP/1.1" 200 39 0.1057
localhost - - [05/Jun/2015:22:36:34 CEST] "POST /sessions HTTP/1.1" 200 39
- -> /sessions
[...]
/pull/table_count HTTP/1.1" 200 21
- -> /sessions/169975329/pull/table_count
NameError - uninitialized constant Config:
 /home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/taps-0.3.24 /lib/taps/utils.rb:17:in `windows?'
 /home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/utils.rb:21:in `bin'
 /home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/utils.rb:132:in `schema_bin'
[...]

ERROR: NameError: uninitialized constant Config
An error occurred but Hoptoad was not notified. To use Hoptoad, please
install the 'hoptoad_notifier' gem and set ENV["HOPTOAD_API_KEY"]
127.0.0.1 - bastien [05/Jun/2015 22:36:35] "POST /sessions/169975329/pull/schema HTTP/1.1" 500 518 0.0039
localhost - - [05/Jun/2015:22:36:35 CEST] "POST /sessions/169975329/pull/schema HTTP/1.1" 500 518
- -> /sessions/169975329/pull/schema
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and there is a patch, that is not merged yet:

https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/pull/144

https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/pull/143

I have the same issue and I think it is because we both use current versions of Ruby (2.2.x)

Comment: I'm fairly new to this. Can we pull the untested version (at our own risk)? Is there any information about where they are on their release cycle (i.e. how long until the fix is available)?